# Postgresql: varchar или text

Tags: sql, postgresql

Документация рекомендует использовать типы `text` и `varchar`. В PostgreSQL обычно используется тип `text`. 
Но знакомый программист сказал, что допустим название товара в таблице должно быть: `varchar`, а описание его должно быть: `text`

Comment: Почему бы вам не попросить этого знакомого программиста рассказать подробнее об этом утверждении? В случае с postgresql используется `text`, тип `varchar` без ограничения длинны используется для совместимости схем с другими БД. Даже `varchar(n)` с ограничением работает хуже судя по ряду утверждений и лучше на колонку повесить `CHECK`.

Comment: То есть в Postgresql нужно использовать всегда text вы советуете?

Comment: Да, в PostgreSQL лучше использовать `text`, на enSO тоже самое говорят: [Difference between text and varchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying).

Comment: @AlexKrass спасибо большое!